# php session['Email'] not showing

Tags: php

I'm trying to start a session after a successful login with session email and display in the page. but somewhere i have made a mistake.

Here is my code on login page

```
if($role == 0){



 $sql = "SELECT id FROM customers WHERE email = '$email' and password = 
 '$password'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1 ) {

      $_SESSION['Email2'] = $_POST['Email']; 

    header("Location:SystemHome.php");




  }else {

     echo " Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
  }
```

And code on the next page,

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php 
echo "Hello".$_SESSION['Email2']."";
?>
```

Comment: Will you share with us what *a mistake* means?

Comment: Did you define `session_start()` in your login script aswell?

Comment: **There are a lot of dangers in this code**. Not using prepared statements. Echoing out user input without sanitation. Storing plain text passwords. You have made many mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add session_start in first page :

```
 session_start(); // start the session

    if($role == 0){



 $sql = "SELECT id FROM customers WHERE email = '$email' and password = 
 '$password'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1 ) {

      $_SESSION['Email2'] = $_POST['Email']; 

    header("Location:SystemHome.php");




  }else {

     echo " Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
  }
```

Comment: You welcome brother , you can use mysql PDO its more secure than mysqli